# Create calendar year variable from daily date

Tags: date, stata

I have a Stata elapsed `date` variable (excerpt below) for each patient `patid`. But I believe I need to generate a new variable if I were to make use of only the year element within that date, that is, not just change the display format.

```
clear
input long patid float date
1015 18766
1018 13135
1020 13325
1025 14384
1029 14514
1050 13501
1070 14523
1071 14878
1090 14701
1092 14159
end
format %td date
```

How do I generate a year variable for all dates within the same year? That is all days from 1st January to 31st December of the same year?

Comment: The question is clear, but I have to say that you are expected to try to read the documentation and to attempt code. I've downvoted on those grounds (lack of research effort).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That calls for just the function `year()`, which together with similar stuff is prominently documented at `help datetime`.

```
clear
input long patid float date
1015 18766
1018 13135
1020 13325
1025 14384
1029 14514
1050 13501
1070 14523
1071 14878
1090 14701
1092 14159
end
format %td date

gen year = year(date) 

list 

     +--------------------------+
     | patid        date   year |
     |--------------------------|
  1. |  1015   19may2011   2011 |
  2. |  1018   18dec1995   1995 |
  3. |  1020   25jun1996   1996 |
  4. |  1025   20may1999   1999 |
  5. |  1029   27sep1999   1999 |
     |--------------------------|
  6. |  1050   18dec1996   1996 |
  7. |  1070   06oct1999   1999 |
  8. |  1071   25sep2000   2000 |
  9. |  1090   01apr2000   2000 |
 10. |  1092   07oct1998   1998 |
     +--------------------------+
```